# How can I use Async Generators in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, generator

I have an api thats going to return a cursor for fetching more data. I've mocked it out like this:

```
function fetch(n) {
  return Promise.resolve({
    results: [n],
    next: next < 10 && n + 1,
  })
}
```

What I'm trying to do is figure out how I can use async/await along with generators in order to interact with this api.

Here's basically what I've prototyped:

```
async function* api(url) {
  let result = await fetch(url)
  yield result
  while (result.next) {
    result = await fetch(result.next)
    yield result
  }
}
```

The idea is that I should be able to create an async generator and yield from that generator in order to iterate through the cursor:

```
async function main() {
  const gen = api(0)
  const zero = await gen.next()
  console.log(zero.result)
  const one = await gen.next()
  console.log(one.result)
  const rest = await Promise.all([...gen])
  console.log(rest.map(r => r.result))
}
```

All things considered, I think this is a pretty sweet way of handling paginated data and being able to pull out all of the data with `[...gen]` is pretty damn cool.

Only problem is, it doesn't work! Apprently you can't use `async` with `function*`:

```
❯❯❯ node --version
v7.0.0
❯❯❯ node --harmony --harmony-async-await async-generator.js
/Users/chetcorcos/code/async-generator.js:11
async function* api(url) {
              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:545:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:607:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:382:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:137:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:497:3
```

But I really feel like this should be possible. There's a popular library called [co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) that I've been poking around with but I don't think that's what I want.

Any ideas how to get this concept of "async generators" to work?

Comment: Have a look at the upcoming proposal https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration . You can use it with Babel's [`babel-plugin-transform-async-generator-functions`](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-async-generator-functions) transform

Comment: Is using `async/await` part of requirement?

Comment: @FelixKling that proposal is epic. Thanks!

Comment: @guest271314 not necessarily part of the requirement -- I've been playing around trying to make it happen without the keywords, but its been a struggle.

Comment: The proposal is at stage 3 btw, so it has good chances becoming part of the spec in 2018 (I don't think it will be part of 2017).

Comment: We can use --js-flags=--harmony-async-iteration now in Chrome Canary but the same flag does not seem to work for Node.js. Thoughts? I was under the impression that they shared javascript engines, but maybe I'm inventing that thought.

Comment: you can down-compile with typescript or simply run natively with nodejs9 with the `--harmony` flag:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694281/ts2318-cannot-find-global-type-asynciterableiterator-async-generator/43694282#43694282

Comment: You can use node 10, node 9 (under the --harmony flag), or use a helper function.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101479/javascript-async-generator/52900682#52900682

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the Babel plugin [transform-async-generator-functions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration).

The usage is like this:

```
const g = async i => [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  .map(x => x * 10 ** i);

const f = async function * () {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const xs = await g(i);
    for (const x of xs) {
      yield x;
    }
  }
};

const main = async () => {
  for await (const x of f()) {
    console.log(x);
  }
};

main().catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Here is [an example repo](https://github.com/njlr/async-generator-example) showing how to setup your project.

The important part is the `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": [ "env" ], 
  "plugins": [ "transform-async-generator-functions" ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass call the generator function as parameter to without using spread element, `Promise.all()` accepts an iterable as parameter which `yield` returns. Note, `Promise.all()` does not resolve or reject the passed `Promise` objects in sequential order, though does return the resulting array in same order as the elements within passed iterable.

```js
let api = (value) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(value)
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 3500))
  })
};

let values = [1, 2, 3];
let results = [];
let gen = function* gen(fn, props) {
  let i = 0; 
  do {
    yield fn(props[i]).then(res => {console.log(res); return res});
    ++i;
  } while (i < props.length);
}

Promise.all(gen(api, values))
.then(data => console.log("complete:", data))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: This looks like it could be a good answer... but the wording is unclear: "You can pass call the generator function as parameter to without using spread element"