# Raising function * into async function *?

Tags: javascript, async-await, generator, babeljs, ecmascript-next

Suppose I have a function that takes a generator and returns another generator of the first `n` elements:

```
const take = function * (n, xs) {
  console.assert(n >= 0);
  let i = 0;
  for (const x of xs) {
    if (i == n) {
      break;
    }
    yield x;
    i++;
  }
};
```

Usage like this:

```
const evens = function * () {
  let i = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield i;
    i += 2;
  }
};

for (const x of take(10, evens())) {
  console.log(x);
}
```

Now imagine that `evens` is also `async` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47830475/1256041) for setup):

```
const evensAsync = async function * () {
  let i = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield i;
    i += 2;
  }
};
```

This, of course, does not work with `take`:

```
const main = async () => {
  for await (const x of take(10, evensAsync())) {
    console.log(x);
  }
};

main().catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Now, I can define a `take` variant that is `async`:

```
const takeAsync = async function * (n, xs) {
  console.assert(n >= 0);
  let i = 0;
  for await (const x of xs) {
    if (i == n) {
      break;
    }
    yield x;
    i++;
  }
};

const main = async () => {
  for await (const x of takeAsync(10, evensAsync())) {
    console.log(x);
  }
};

main().catch(e => console.error(e));
```

... *but what a hassle!*

Is there a way to automatically "asyncify" generator functions in JavaScript?

Comment: async iteration proposal: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration

Comment: [Possibly interesting article.](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/async-iterators-and-generators/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to automatically "asyncify" generator functions in JavaScript?

No. Asynchronous and synchronous generators are just too different. You will need two different implementations of your `take` function, there's no way around it.

You can however dynamically select which one to choose:

```
async function* takeAsync(asyncIterable) { … }
function* takeSync(iterable) { … }

function take(obj) {
    if (typeof obj[Symbol.asyncIterator] == "function") return takeAsync(obj);
    if (typeof obj[Symbol.iterator] == "function") return takeSync(obj);
    throw new TypeError("not an iterable object");
}
```

It is not in general possible to write a function `asyncify` that could be used like `asyncify(takeSync)(10, evensAsync())`. One might be able to hack something together that works for `takeSync` and `mapSync`, relying on the fact that they output exactly one item per input item, but it would be pretty brittle and not work for other iteration functions like `filter`.

That said, it is of course possible to generalise and provide abstractions.

```
function taker(n) {
  return {
    done: n > 0,
    *step(element) { /* if (n > 0) */ yield element; return taker(n-1); },
    result: null
  }
}
function mapper(fn) {
  return {
    done: false,
    *step(element) { yield fn(element); return this; }
    result: null
  }
}

function makeIterator(t) {
  return function*(iterable) {
    for (let element of iterable) {
      t = yield* t.step(element);
      if (t.done) break;
    }
    return t.result;
  };
}
function makeAsyncIterator(t) {
  return async function*(asyncIterable) {
    for await (let element of asyncIterable) {
      t = yield* t.step(element);
      if (t.done) break;
    }
    return t.result;
  };
}
```

(which shamelessly rips off the [transducer concept](https://github.com/cognitect-labs/transducers-js#the-transducer-protocol) - also not tested for anything)