# How do I gather an async function * into an array?

Tags: javascript, async-await, generator

Suppose I have an `async function * ()` ([setup here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350787/how-can-i-use-async-generators-in-javascript/47830475#47830475)) like this:

```
const f = async function * () {
  yield * [ 1, 2, 3 ];
};
```

I can gather the results like this:

```
const xs = [];

for await (const x of f()) {
  xs.push(x);
}
```

But can I use the `...` syntax to make this more compact?

Something like:

```
const xs = await f(); // xs = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Comment: `Promise.all(f())` might be reasonable, though I don't think the current proposal supports that extension.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure spread syntax will stay reserved for synchronous iterables.

Comment: Not a complete remedy but there is a proposal for a closely related feature: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-array-from-async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is put it into a function:

```
const toArray = async f => {
  const xs = []; 
  for await (const x of f) {
    xs.push(x);
  }
  return xs;
};
```

Usage:

```
// In an async context
const xs = await toArray(f());
```